# Wordpress Ubuntu redirects DigitalOcean Issue

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, redirect

Good day:
I have my website in digitalOcean, in Ubuntu Droplet. I have both Wordpress site and CakePHP sites.  CakePHP is working well.

Wordpress I have a little issue:
If I access for example www.mywebpage.cl then it shows my "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" page (apache1.jpg attached):
If I access on my browser: 
http://www.mywebpage.cl/alianzaWordpress/datos1/ then it goes to my webpage (mysite.jpg).

I want to go to www.mywebpage.cl and automatically directs to http://www.mywebpage.cl/alianzaWordpress/datos1/

I have tried to modify /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf with no success.
I have tried set DocumentRoot as /var/www/html/alianzaWordpress/datos1 or  but still not working properly

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html/alianzaWordpress/datos1
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

After I modify I do "a2enmod rewrite ; service apache2 restart"
enter image description here
Please any recommendation is fine for me, also I am using permalinks "post names" in my site. (permalinks.jpg)

Regards,
Felipe[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBOHs.jpg)

Pictures[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something easy to do, thanks anyway.

I modifed this file /var/www/html/index.html with this information to redirect to the folder I wanted:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mywebpage.cl/alianzaWordpress/datos1/">
```

Sorry for easy question, now I learn, Regards,
Felipe